# UI child items inside UI panel object aren't selectable in Unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have parent UI image object which is also a prefub. Inside UI image I have UI buttons. When I click on a child button in editor it doesn't get selected in hierarchy. Instead of it the only parent object (the UI image) is selected in hierarchy and a green border is apperead arount the parant UI image object.
Also sometimes a child object is selectable.
I have unity 2021.30f1 editor.
All Gizmos are on.

Here is the sceen of green border:
[image]

Comment: Click twice.  If there are object blocking, unity will choose the top most object.  If you subsequently click again, the selection will pass through to objects below.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I know it, it doesn't work